# How to obtain a formula for the integral of the step function

Tags: real-analysis

F(x) is defined to be the integral from 1 to x of f(x) which is equal to the step function of x. If x takes values in [1,3], how do we obtain a formula for the integral of f(x)?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

if $x \le1 , \; I=0$

if $1 <x \le 2 , I=\int_1^xf (x)dx=(x-1) $

if $2 <x\le 3 , I=1+\int_2^xf (x)dx=2 (x-2)+1$.